# calling a function of a class, but passed as an argument

Tags: c++, eigen

I am quite new in C++ programming (but much more used to IDL and Python). I am actually trying to re-write a code that I have already written in IDL into C++, to improve its efficiency. In my project, I wish to call a function within a class, from another class. Below, I copied what I think is the essential part of the code required to understand the problem. However, I simplified it in order to improve its clarity.

When compiling with g++, I obtain the following error:

```
MALA.cpp: In member function ‘void MALA::update_position_MH(Model_def*, Data*, Config*, int)’:
MALA.cpp:277:52: error: no matching function for call to ‘Model_def::call_model(Data&)’
propos_model=(*model_class).call_model(*data_struc); // PROBLEM HERE! TO DEBUG!
                                                ^
In file included from MALA.h:13:0, 
                 from MALA.cpp:29:
 model_def.h:34:12: note: candidate: Eigen::VectorXd Model_def::call_model(Data*)
      VectorXd call_model(Data *data_struc); // call a model using its name
        ^
 model_def.h:34:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Data’ to ‘Data*’
```

What I do not understand is that the code compiles without errors if I comment the line (see at the very end of the given code):

```
 propos_model=(*model_class).call_model(*data_struc); // PROBLEM HERE!
```

But then, why I do not get an error as well for the line:

```
vars_new=new_prop_values((*model_class).vars, m); // This works fine
```

What am I doing wrong when passing the structure 'Data' as an argument of the function call_model?

Here is the simplified code, spread in different files:

**This is the model_def.h (simplified)**

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <string>
#include "config.h"
#include "data.h"

class Model_def{
       string model_name;
       bool relax[];
       int plength[];
       VectorXd cons;
       long Ncons, Nvars, Nparams;
       string vars_names[];
       string cons_names[];
       string params_names[];
    public:
       Model_def(string m_name, bool rlx[], int plgth, VectorXd params_in, string params_in_names); // The constructor
       Eigen::VectorXd params;
       Eigen::VectorXd vars;
       Eigen::VectorXd call_model(Data *data_struc);
};
```

**This is the model_def.cpp (simplified)**

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "model_def.h"

Eigen::VectorXd Model_def::call_model(Data *data_struc){

    bool passed=0;

    if(model_name == "Model_MS_Global"){
       passed=1;
       return Model_MS_Global(params, plength, (*data_struc).x); // This function is in a dedicated cpp file (not shown here)
     }

// Other things happening...
}
```

**This is the data.h**

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <string>
struct Data{
    Eigen::VectorXd x;
    Eigen::VectorXd y;
    long Nx; // Ny is not checked but should be as long as x
    string xlabel[];
    string ylabel[];
};
```

**This is the MALA.h (simplified)**

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <string>
#include "model_def.h"

class MALA{
    private:
        int seed; // to generate random numbers
        double epsilon1;
        Eigen::MatrixXd epsilon2;
        double A1;
        double delta;
        double delta_x;
    public:
        void update_position_MH(Model_def *model_class, Data *data_struc, Config *cfg_class, int m);
 };
```

**This is the MALA.cpp (simplified)**

```
void MALA::update_position_MH(Model_def *model_class, Data *data_struc, Config *cfg_class, int m){

    VectorXd vars_new;
    double* u=uniform_01(1, &seed ); // Generate uniform random number between 0 and 1
    VectorXd propos_model;

    if((*cfg_class).proposal_type == "Random"){
        vars_new=new_prop_values((*model_class).vars, m); // This works fine
    }

    propos_model=(*model_class).call_model(*data_struc); // PROBLEM HERE!

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data_struc is a pointer, and call_model wants a pointer, so you just pass it directly.  Putting a * in front "dereferences" it and makes it not a pointer anymore.

```
 propos_model=(*model_class).call_model(data_struc);
```

Or, a bit better

```
 propos_model = model_class->call_model(data_struc);
```

Comment: Thanks. This helps, but another problem appears when I pass the pointer. I get the following error:
      /tmp/ccQrC19V.o: In function `MALA::update_position_MH(Model_def*, Data*, Config*, int)':
      MALA.cpp:(.text+0x2310): undefined reference to  `Model_def::call_model(Data*)'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

What else am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ok, maybe there is a problem with the assignment to VectorXd. That class isn't shown above..

Comment: Actually VectorXd is defined in the Eigen library.  Above the lines that I have shown for the file MALA.cpp, I have an include of the Eigen library (`#include <Eigen/Dense>`) and the line `using Eigen::VectorXd;`

Comment: Ok, you posted the error now.  That error is a linker error saying that your program compiled ok, but there are pieces missing.  It can't find the call_model function.  Are you building shared libraries (which can be complicated)? Are you missing a c++ file in your build script?

Comment: @tomahna You agree that the answer above solves the problem you posted. You should [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it by clicking the green check mark. The solution has enabled you to discover another problem. In that case, if you can't solve it yourself, you can ask another question. One question at a time!

Comment: Ah, yes! I am not used yet with g++ and I simply forgot to add the model_def.cpp into the compilation line. Thanks!